# Retention rate over years in POWER BI

Tags: graph, powerbi, calculation, rate, retention

I have the enrolment number which changes year by year, I want to calculate the retention Rate.

2017: 1137
2018:1128
2019:1002
2020:1063
2021:763

How to calculate the retention rate in this particular case.

1. A graph which shows the retention rate year over year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this measure:

```
Retention Rate = 
VAR thisYear = 
    MAX(MyTable[Year])
VAR prevYear = 
    thisYear - 1
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(MyTable[Enrollment Number]),
            MyTable[Year] = thisYear
        ),
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(MyTable[Enrollment Number]),
            MyTable[Year] = prevYear
        )
    )
```

which looks like this in a column chart:

[image]